# SQL Join on two tables that both give argument for WHERE clause

Tags: java, sql

Does the following SQL Query work?

```
SELECT domains.domainURL, passwords.* FROM domains LEFT JOIN passwords ON domains.id = passwords.domainId WHERE domains.domainURL = {1} AND passwords.userId = {2};
```

The SQL Query shall receive the password that the user has saved for a specific domain(PW Manager). Therefore I have the user Id and the domainURL. I need to receive the domain Id from another table with the domainURL. Then I need to receive the password from the passwords table with the user Id and the domainId as argument.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: @Nightloewe . . . Describe what YOU mean by "work".  Sample data and desired results would help clarify what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this query "work"?

```
SELECT d.domainURL, p.*
FROM domains d LEFT JOIN
     passwords p
     ON d.id = p.domainId
WHERE d.domainURL = {1} AND p.userId = {2};
```

Well, it should not result in an error -- assuming that the tables and columns are correct.  Does it do what you want?  Well, if you want an `INNER JOIN`, it does what you want.

I suspect that you might intend:

```
SELECT d.domainURL, p.*
FROM domains d LEFT JOIN
     passwords p
     ON d.id = p.domainId AND p.userId = {2} 
WHERE d.domainURL = {1};
```

This will return the row from `passwords` *if it exists*.  It will return all rows from `domains` that match the `WHERE` clause.